# python - get list of tuples first index?

Tags: python, list, tuples

What's the most compact way to return the following:

Given a list of tuples, return a list consisting of the tuples first (or second, doesn't matter) elements.

For:

```
[(1,'one'),(2,'two'),(3,'three')]
```

returned list would be

```
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

use zip if you need both

```
>>> r=(1,'one'),(2,'two'),(3,'three')
>>> zip(*r)
[(1, 2, 3), ('one', 'two', 'three')]
```

Comment: @bourbaki4481472 yes in Python 3: list(zip(*r))

Answer (score 42):

```
>>> tl = [(1,'one'),(2,'two'),(3,'three')]
>>> [item[0] for item in tl]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> mylist = [(1,'one'),(2,'two'),(3,'three')]
>>> [j for i,j in mylist]
['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> [i for i,j in mylist]
[1, 2, 3]
```

This is using a [list comprehension (have a look at this link)](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html). So it iterates through the elements in `mylist`, setting `i` and `j` to the two elements in the tuple, in turn. It is effectively equivalent to:

```
>>> newlist = []
>>> for i, j in mylist:
...     newlist.append(i)
... 
>>> newlist
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: it's a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[0], my_list))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this too..

```
dict(my_list).keys()
```

Comment: Never do like this. Because index will be changed.

Comment: @Shameem plz elaborate with an example.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the question completely. I mean the index of output list will be different from input list. But he doesn't matter.