# Convert list of tuples to list?

Tags: python

How do I convert

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
```

to

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - get list of tuples first index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735282/python-get-list-of-tuples-first-index)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Using simple [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
e = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
[i[0] for i in e]
```

will give you:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 72):

@Levon's solution works perfectly for your case.

As a side note, if you have variable number of elements in the tuples, you can also use `chain` from `itertools`.

```
>>> a = [(1, ), (2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(a))
[(1,), (2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
>>> list(chain(*a))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(a)) # More efficient version than unpacking
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This was very handy for me, thanks. Because chain returns an iterator you can do things like `max(chain.from_iterable(a))`. It's also very easy to insert this into another generator expression or list comprehension.

Answer (score 35):

Here is another alternative if you can have a variable number of elements in the tuples:

```
>>> a = [(1,), (2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
>>> [x for t in a for x in t]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This is basically just a shortened form of the following loops:

```
result = []
for t in a:
    for x in t:
        result.append(x)
```

Comment: Best answer by far, beautifully concise/generalizable. But the syntax is pretty mind-bending. Is that last `for` statement analogous to a trailing `if` statement on a list comprehension, e.g. `[i for i in range(10) if i%2==0]`? I'm familiar with the latter.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> a = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
>>> zip(*a)[0]
(1, 2, 3)
```

For a list:

```
>>> list(zip(*a)[0])
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I'm more familiar and comfortable with it too, but I'm trying to learn more about zip and itertools, so this is instructive :)

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> a = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
>>> b = map(lambda x: x[0], a)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
```

With python3, you have to put the list(..) function to the output of map(..), i.e.

```
b = list(map(lambda x: x[0], a))
```

This is the best solution in **one line** using python built-in functions.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `sum` function as follows:

```
e = [(1,), (2,), (3,)] 
e_list = list(sum(e, ()))
```

And it also works with list of lists to convert it into a single list, but you will need to use it as follow:

```
e = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
e_list = list(sum(e, []))
```

This will give you `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: Could you kindly explain how this achieves the answer?

Answer (score 4):

There's always a way to extract a list from another list by **...`for`...`in`...**. In this case it would be:

**`[i[0] for i in e]`**

Answer (score 4):

Using operator or sum

```
>>> from functools import reduce ### If python 3
>>> import operator
>>> a = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
>>> list(reduce(operator.concat, a))
[1, 2, 3]
```

(OR)

```
>>> list(sum(a,()))
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

If in python > 3 please do the import of reduce from functools 
like `from functools import reduce`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Comment: NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined

Answer (score 3):

You can also unpack the tuple in the list comprehension:

```
e = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
[i for (i,) in e]
```

will still give:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

**One Liner yo!**

```
list(*zip(*[(1,), (2,), (3,)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In these situations I like to do:

```
a = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
new_a = [element for tup in a for element in tup]
```

This works even if your tuples have more than one element. This is equivalent to doing this:

```
a = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
new_a = []
for tup in a:
    for element in tup:
        new_a.append(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is already a numpy array, use `ravel()` method which is more faster than list comprehension.

If it is already a list, list comprehension is better.

> Most of the answers above only prints the first element not all the elements

**For numpy arrays**

```
#arr = np.array([(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)])

#faster than list comprehension
arr.ravel().tolist()

#output => [1,2,2,3,3,4]
```

**For list**

```
list_ = [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]

[x for y in list_ for x in y]

#output => [1,2,2,3,3,4]
```