# Convert list of single element tuples to list of elements

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert list of tuples to list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941229/convert-list-of-tuples-to-list)

I have a list like this

```
[('Knightriders',), ('The Black Knight',), ('Fly by Knight',), ('An Arabian Knight',), ('A Bold, Bad Knight',)...]
```

I want to convert this to :

```
['Knightriders', 'The Black Knight', 'Fly by Knight', 'An Arabian Knight', 'A Bold, Bad Knight',...]
```

What is the least time consuming way to accomplish this ?

Comment: How did you end up with this list? **What did you try**?

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer I fetched a single column from a postgres table in python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

simplest one is using a list comprehension:

```
In [126]: lis=[('Knightriders',), ('The Black Knight',), ('Fly by Knight',), ('An Arabian Knight',), ('A Bold, Bad Knight',)]

In [127]: [x[0] for x in lis]
Out[127]: 
['Knightriders',
 'The Black Knight',
 'Fly by Knight',
 'An Arabian Knight',
 'A Bold, Bad Knight']
```

or using `itemgetter`:

```
In [128]: from operator import itemgetter

In [129]: list(map(itemgetter(0),lis))
Out[129]: 
['Knightriders',
 'The Black Knight',
 'Fly by Knight',
 'An Arabian Knight',
 'A Bold, Bad Knight']
```

or:

```
In [131]: [next(x) for x in map(iter,lis)]
Out[131]: 
['Knightriders',
 'The Black Knight',
 'Fly by Knight',
 'An Arabian Knight',
 'A Bold, Bad Knight']
```

or using `zip()` as suggested by @DSM:

```
In [132]: zip(*lis)[0]
Out[132]: 
('Knightriders',
 'The Black Knight',
 'Fly by Knight',
 'An Arabian Knight',
 'A Bold, Bad Knight')
```

or using `ast.literal_eval`(least recommended solution or may be never try this):

```
In [148]: from ast import literal_eval

In [149]: literal_eval(repr(lis).replace(",)",")"))
Out[149]: 
['Knightriders',
 'The Black Knight',
 'Fly by Knight',
 'An Arabian Knight',
 'A Bold, Bad Knight']
```

Comment: There's also `list(zip(*lis)[0])`.

Comment: @DSM oh! I missed that one. :)

Comment: If data contains the list, one could do something like `eval(repr(data).replace('(', '').replace(',)', ''))` :-). And no, nobody should do it this way. Kids, don't do this at home!

Comment: @Matthias `literal_eval(repr(lis).replace(",)",")"))` is safe for kids. :)

Comment: Shame on me! But to make it clear for anybody who wants to use it: DON'T DO IT!

Comment: What about a speed comparision?