# Convert list of tuple-1 of float to set of int

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

After querying a database, I get a result `r` of the following format:

```
r = [(123.0,), (456.0,), (789.0,)]
```

That is a list of `tuple`s, each with one item which is a `float` (that is actually an `int`).

I would like to convert that to a `set` of `int`s:

```
s = {123, 456, 789}
```

I expected this to be a trivial `map()`, but I can't seem to write it. How do I tell `map()` I want to take the first element of the tuple?

I know that `int(r[0][0])` gives me the first element of my `set`, `int(r[1][0])` the second, `int(r[2][0])` the third and so on, but how do I "industrialize" this?

Comment: Did you mean `r = [(123.0,), (456.0,), (789.0,)]` ?

Comment: Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941229/convert-list-of-tuples-to-list I learned about "List Comprehensions" and found ForceBru first solution by myself: {int(t[0]) for t in r} Since my actual query returns millions of records, I'll be able to tell you which of the three is the fastest. Edit: Missed the answers already here. You guys are fast! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
result = {int(x[0]) for x in r}
```

If you want to go full `map` ninja:

```
In [1]: import operator
In [2]: set(map(int, map(operator.itemgetter(0), r)))                          
Out[2]: {123, 456, 789}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map`:

```
set(map(lambda x: int(x[0]), r))
```

Comment: I think this is more pythonic then the second

Comment: @khelilimiliana, just for inmmediate use. Operator lib functions are much more performant than lambdas. But if there is no need for it to be really performant is ok with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My program executes 2 jobs of 2 queries on separate databases (in order to compare the results): The queries of the first job return 35,694,726 records (tuples in the list).
The second job results in 47,176,395 tuples (in both lists).

In total there are 4 large lists to convert, giving some idea about the relative speed of the solutions.

All 3 solutions yield two set of 35,694,726 respectively 47,176,395 items. OK.

In each solution the first query result is treated faster than the second one. I guess one is better ordered than the other or something?

Here under, a result of "16.5/20.4/25.8/36.7" indicates that the first list of tuples was converted to a set in 16.5 seconds, that the second one took 20.4 seconds, third 25.5 and last 36.7 seconds.

- `Operator Lib Function   : 16.5/20.4/25.8/36.7`
- `Using List Comprehension: 16.3/20.8/28.3/37.0`
- `Map+Lambda              : 17.8/22.0/30.8/38.8`

So there *is* a difference, but not much. The (concurrently executed) queries take 5 minutes, so a few seconds don't make a big difference, over all.

Map+Lambda is the slowest, as was predicted above. Since List Comprehension is a concise way of writing and does not need an import, that will be my solution of choice here.