# Python list of tuples to list of int

Tags: python, list, tuples

So, I have `x=[(12,), (1,), (3,)]` (list of tuples) and I want `x=[12, 1, 3]` (list of integers) in best way possible? Can you please help?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your attempt at a solution. Thank you.

Comment: are your tuples always of the same form? `(n,)` ?

Comment: An alternative `zip(*x)[0]` or `next(zip(*x))` on Py3k

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - get list of tuples first index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735282/python-get-list-of-tuples-first-index)

Answer (score 14):

You didn't say what you mean by "best", but presumably you mean "most pythonic" or "most readable" or something like that.

The list comprehension given by F3AR3DLEGEND is probably the simplest. Anyone who knows how to read a list comprehension will immediately know what it means.

```
y = [i[0] for i in x]
```

However, often you don't really need a list, just something that can be iterated over once. If you've got a billion elements in `x`, building a billion-element `y` just to iterate over it one element at a time may be a bad idea. So, you can use a generator expression:

```
y = (i[0] for i in x)
```

If you prefer functional programming, you might prefer to use `map`. The downside of `map` is that you have to pass it a function, not just an expression, which means you either need to use a `lambda` function, or `itemgetter`:

```
y = map(operator.itemgetter(0), x)
```

In Python 3, this is equivalent to the generator expression; if you want a `list`, pass it to `list`. In Python 2, it returns a `list`; if you want an iterator, use `itertools.imap` instead of `map`.

If you want a more generic flattening solution, you can write one yourself, but it's always worth looking at [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) for generic solutions of this kind, and there is in fact a recipe called `flatten` that's used to "Flatten one level of nesting". So, copy and paste that into your code (or `pip install more-itertools`) and you can just do this:

```
y = flatten(x)
```

If you look at how `flatten` is implemented, and then at how `chain.from_iterable` is implemented, and then at how `chain` is implemented, you'll notice that you could write the same thing in terms of builtins. But why bother, when `flatten` is going to be more readable and obvious?

Finally, if you want to reduce the generic version to a nested list comprehension (or generator expression, of course):

```
y = [j for i in x for j in i]
```

However, nested list comprehensions are very easy to get wrong, both in writing and reading. (Note that F3AR3DLEGEND, the same person who gave the simplest answer first, also gave a nested comprehension and got it wrong. If he can't pull it off, are you sure you want to try?) For really simple cases, they're not too bad, but still, I think `flatten` is a lot easier to read.

Comment: So what is your opinion on tuple unpacking à la pattern matching?

Comment: @PavelAnossov: What about it? When you want to unpack a tuple into separate named variables, it's obviously exactly the right thing. When you have a tuple of one that you just want to turn into a single value, it doesn't seem quite as clear, but it's not really objectionable.

Answer (score 5):

```
y = [i[0] for i in x]
```

This only works for one element per tuple, though.

However, if you have multiple elements per tuple, you can use a slightly more complex list comprehension:

```
y = [i[j] for i in x for j in range(len(i))]
```

Reference: [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions)

Comment: @pedro - Yes, it will always have one element.

Comment: For the second one: If you need to flatten any sequence of sequences, there's a recipe in the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) docs called `flatten`. It's probably worth understanding both that and the list comprehension.

Comment: Shouldn't you inverse the order of the `for`s?

Comment: Also, why are you even iterating over `range(len(i))` just to get the values by index? `i[j] for j in range(len(i))` is exactly the same as `j for j in i`.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
x = [i[0] for i in x]
```

Explanation:

```
>>> x=[(12,), (1,), (3,)]

>>> x
[(12,), (1,), (3,)]

>>> [i for i in x]
[(12,), (1,), (3,)]

>>> [i[0] for i in x]
[12, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most efficient way:

```
x = [i for i, in x]
```

or, equivalently

```
x = [i for (i,) in x]
```

This is a bit slower:

```
x = [i[0] for i in x]
```

Comment: Are you sure about the efficiency difference? In a quick test with a 1M-element `list` in 3.3.0, they took 4.15ms and 4.14ms respectively—and it looks like more than 4ms of that was the time spent iterating the list and building a new list, so nothing is likely to be any faster. If you change x to a genexp and replace the two listcomps with a genexp fed to `deque(genexp, maxlen=0)`, I get 1.36us vs. 1.32us.

Comment: More importantly, what scenario are you imagining where anyone would care which of these two is more efficient?

Comment: Where's this efficiency trend for Python on SO coming from anyway? To me, it seems like a trick to gain more points.

Comment: @phant0m: Some people see "best way" and immediately interpret that as "the most efficient way". I have no idea why those people are coding in Python rather than C. Especially the kind of people who make assumptions instead of testing—don't those kind of people assume that C is always going to be fastest?

Comment: I tested it on python 2.7, this is not an assumption (34ms vs. 46ms with a 1M list). I'd say readability of these ways is pretty close, so what else is there to compare to choose the "best" (which nobody defined)?

Comment: Assuming "best" means "most efficient" is almost never a good idea. Again, can you imagine any situation where that 30% improvement would make a difference—but the factor of 4000x or so involved in excess list building would not?

Answer (score 0):

you can use map function....

```
map(lambda y: y[0], x)
```

Comment: If you're going to use `map`, you might as well use `itemgetter` instead of a `lambda`.