# I need to remove o rnot include the ',' in my result

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

My problem is when I query my database like so

```
upperBound.extend(cursor.execute(queryUpper, ['SN00010', '2015-05-07 22:16:00.810']).fetchall())
```

Where queryUpper grabs the upper bounds column from the database and ['SN00010', '2015-05-07 22:16:00.810'] fills in some parameters to the query my result list returns

```
[(15497,), (14957,), (14516,), (14159,), (12164,), (11597,), (11555,), (11513,)]
```

I also have a query to get the lower bounds column and I want to use range() to obviously find the range between the bounds. The problem is that its returning an extra comma (parenthesis also which I don't think matter) that I need to remove from each element or somehow not include when the list is made. Im not sure if it matters but I am using pypyodbc and  MSSQL server

Comment: The *"extra comma"* indicates that you have a list of tuples...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096021/python-list-of-tuples-to-list-of-int) may help you in converting it to a more useful format.

Comment: Thank you Red Shift that works out great. Thank god I do not have a Billion elements