# Iterate over a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I  have a list of tuples in this format:

```
my_list = [(1,4),(3,6),(10,7)]
```

I want to print the second elements of each tupple:

```
4,6,7
```

I can access those values as:

```
my_list[0][1]
my_list[1][1]
my_list[2][1]
```

But that isn't a reasonable approach for any reasonable size list, for now, and doing using list comprehension:

```
[x[1] for x in my_list ]
```

Is there any solution that doesn't imply to use a loop?
something like:

```
my_list[:][1]
```

I tried to do it that way but got:

```
(3, 6)
```

Comment: If the order of elements dont matter you can try this `dict(my_list).values()` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[:]` just creates a copy of the list, so `[1]` indexes that copy. And no, outside of NumPy arrays, there is technically no way to avoid a loop. The loop may be done in C code in a function like `map()`, but there's going to be a loop anyway.

Using `map()` for example applies a callable for each element in your input list:

```
map(lambda nested: nested[1], my_list)
```

or

```
from operator import itemgetter

map(itemgetter(1), my_list)
```

Both work in Python 2, in Python 3 you need to wrap the `map()` call in a `list()` call to drive the iteration.

Either way, I find a list comprehension to be clearer here anyway.

Comment: Is it a different solution in case of numpy arrays?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez: Numpy arrays support multiple dimensions and you'd address this as one column in a matrix: `matrix[:, 1]`. See the [NumPy QuickStart](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [python get list of tuples first index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735282/python-get-list-of-tuples-first-index)

try with `zip`

```
my_list = [(1,4),(3,6),(10,7)]

print zip(*my_list)[1]

(4, 6, 7)
```

Comment: Do explain that `zip()` includes a loop and produces two separate tuples in full, one of which you discard again.