# Python dictionary getting first value of tuple

Tags: python

I have a dictionary -

```
p = {"a": [(0,1),(0,3)]}
```

I want to fetch only the first value of each tuple i.e, 0 in this case.

```
p["a"]
```

gives me [(0,1),(0,3)]
 but I want [0,0]
Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - get list of tuples first index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735282/python-get-list-of-tuples-first-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try `list comprehension`:

```
p = {"a": [(0,1),(0,3)]}
# key to search
k = 'a'

res = [element[0] for element in p.get(k,[])]
print(res)
```

Result:

```
[0, 0]
```

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop over it

```
[x[0] for x in p["a"]]
```

Comment: What if p has another key like `b` ?

Comment: Then do it again with `"a"` replaced with `"b"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
d = {k:[i[0] for i in v] for k,v in p.items()}

> d
{'a': [0, 0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p = {"a": [(0,1),(0,3)]}

for i in p["a"]:
    print(i[0])
```

Try this one...